# Deployment Error for JAX-WS Webapp

Tags: tomcat7, jax-ws

Bit of a strange one here, that has me completely blocked.

I have a webapp, with some JAX-WS annotated classes. Also, when the webapp is deployed, a third party framework is initialized, using a listener `ThirdPartyContextListener` in `web.xml`. So far so good. (For info, the framework is responsible for ORM, caching and data persistence.)

The trouble starts when some of my JAX-WS classes need to use the framework. It seems that the framework has not been initialised (via the `ThirdPartyContextListener`) early enough. As in, it seems that when the web service classes are instantiated, `ThirdPartyContextListener` hasn't yet been invoked.

The listeners are definitely in the correct order in my `web.xml`, so I would expect my `ThirdPartyContextListener` to be the first piece of code to get executed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

    ... stuff here ...

    <listener>
        <listener-class>ThirdPartyContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    ... stuff here also ...

</web-app>
```

So I have a couple of questions:

- Why are the JAX-WS classes instantiated so early? (Or at least look this way)
- Is there a way to **force** the framework to be initialised first

Unfortunately I can't really give code samples (security restrictions from my work place).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the following lines in my log:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
```

So it would seem JAX-WS is doing some work before the of the `listeners` get hit; from the looks of it , it's creating delegates for each of the services endpoints I have defined. I'm fairly certain you cannot alter the order of `XxxxContainerInitializer`, so I looked at other alternatives. One of these was to use `spring` to look after the webservices.

This required a few more JARs, some of which were conflicting with the third party framework we are suing. This was quickly making our solution a little *too* complex... so I stopped trying to be clever and just used lazy  singletons instead.

(Sounds awful, but it suits us better because each service call requires a call to the third party framework anyway.)